# Mordell curves with large rank

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

An elliptic curve is (for the purpose of this question) a cubic algebraic curve defined by an equation (short Weierstrass equation) of the form

$$\displaystyle E_{a,b} : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, 4a^3 + 27b^2 \ne 0.$$

The elliptic curves with $a = 0$ are called *Mordell curves*.

Do we have examples of Mordell curves with large algebraic rank, say exceeding 10?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, this record is still held by a 3-isogenous pair of
Mordell curves of rank $\bf 17$ that I found and announced in February 2016.
(This superseded a rank-16 pair from earlier that month, and curves of ranks
13, 14, 15 from October 2009.)

The curves $y^2 = x^3 + b$ and $y^2 = x^3 - 27 b$
are always related by an isogeny of degree $3$,
and in particular have the same rank.
The record $b,-27b$ have
$$ b = -908800736629952526116772283648363 $$
(in factored form, $-2195745961 \cdot 413891567044514092637683$).
The curve $y^2 = x^3 - 27 b$ has $17$ independent points

```
[-110315760690, 152299457785937151],
[-218829008658, 118569576333381183],
[194693247690, 178654854781822599],
[-12083686365, 156639252691623474],
[179588218407, 174154202398188288],
[660796972800, 559532270810391651],
[481938369495, 369425010854453724],
[532637728899, 419104420151289750],
[891937317975, 856808203106532276],
[1556910033324, 1948958451538253955],
[1369152212199, 1609695603071293320],
[-249954149276, 94452185380426435],
[527526224524, 413931980240076925],
[2095375244992, 3037184017947911267],
[3020920353232, 5252935870900542563],
[45908680009155, 311058636438867847974],
[209109621212430, 3023855428577131273599].
```

Comment: Where did you initially announce this result?

Comment: Offline, Noam told me that the rank-16 pair was announced on the [NMBRTHRY mailing list](https://web.archive.org/web/20230313153923/https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=NMBRTHRY;fc0d1ed0.1602) but he couldn't quite recall exactly how/where he announced the rank 17 example above.

Comment: I received an announcement of the rank 17 curve in an email titled "j=0, rank 17" from Noam on Feb 23, 2016 (I was one of a dozen recipients). This document is dated Feb 18, 2016 https://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/many_pts_asu.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Apparently Tom Womack used to maintain a webpage devoted to Mordell curves of high rank at the (no longer functional) page [here](http://www.tom.womack.net/maths/mordellc.htm) although it can be viewed with the help of the Wayback Machine. This reports that the curves with
$$ k = 35470887868736225 \text{ and } k = -46111487743732324 $$
have rank $11$, while the curve with
$$ k = -6533891544658786928 $$
has rank $12$. This rank 12 curve was found by Jordi Quer in connection with searching for imaginary quadratic fields of high $3$-rank (see the paper ''[Corps quadratiques de 3-rang 6 et courbes elliptiques de rang 12](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54952139/f15.item)'' in C. R. Acad. Sc. Paris. from 1987). Quer reports two more rank 12 Mordell curves in this paper.

Elkies and Rodgers also found a rank $11$ curve of the form $x^{3} + y^{3} = k$ (isomorphic to $y^{2} = x^{3} - 432k^{2}$) in their 2004 ANTS paper.

I do not know if any of these results have been improved recently.